# UWP CompactOverlay Mode (Picture-inPicture) IsViewModeSupported Exception

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

Currently i'm testing the new CompactOverlay Mode, but there seems to be a Problem, when running the app not on the Creators Update (e.g. Anniversary Update). Here is a simplified Piece of Code

```
// Check if it is supported
if (ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsViewModeSupported(ApplicationViewMode.CompactOverlay))
{
  // Supported
}
else
{
  // Not supported
}
```

But this gives me an exception, on versions of Windows before Creators Update:

```
System.InvalidCastException: ‘Unable to cast object of type ‘Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView’ to type ‘Windows.UI.ViewManagement.IApplicationView4
```

Is this a bug, or do i need to check against something other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected. The API is new in the Creators Update and therefore won't work on earlier versions of the OS. The IsViewModeSupported API will tell you if the device you are running on (PC, phone, xbox, etc.) supports the respective viewmode. Before you can make that this check you should first check that the viewmode API itself is there. You can do this with the following [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.apiinformation)

Comment: Thank you very much! Marked your answer as solution.